# MIPS branch delay slot and bnez using same register

Tags: assembly, mips

I have following asm MIPS code:

```
80031DB8  bnez    $v0, loc_80031F58
80031DBC  move    $v0, $zero
```

as far as I understand "branch not equal zero" will never jump to loc_80031F58, because v0 = 0, is that right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  At the time of comparison, `$v0` has whatever value prior to execution of `80031DB8`.  After the comparison, when the delay slot executes and the jump is beginning to be taken, `$v0` is written with the value `0`.

Once the branch is either taken or not taken, `$v0` has the value zero.  That is, at the start of execution of either `80031F58` (when the branch is taken) or 80031DC0 (when the branch is not taken), `$v0` will be `0`, although if the branch is taken, it must have had a non-zero value previously.

Comment: Thank you for awesome and fast answer.